# How to run/test a file in Python?

Tags: python, pycharm

Let me first state that I am *very new* to Python.

I have as an assignment a .py file that I am to complete, but I don't know how to run it. The file has:

```
def some_func(filename):
    ....
    ....
    ....

def main():
    ....
    ....
    ....
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'm using PyCharm, how do I run this  script? I'd like to test my code. I tried running it by right clicking the file and selecting Run myfile.py, which is how I've done it in the past, but I don't know how to do it with this file.

Answer (score 2):

### From the commandline:

```
python /path/to/file/to/run.py
```

### From PyCharm (assuming you have already [setup a project](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/importing-project-from-existing-source-code.html))

First time:

1. Run -> Run... (or alt+ctrl+R)
2. Select filename

Subsequent times:

1. Run -> Run '<filename>' or press green play button or ctrl+R

[image: Hitting 'Run' button in PyCharm interface]